# struct not recognized in eclipse cdt

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to write a console-based calculator by eclipse cdt.But there seems to be a problem with recognize my struct Calc

There is my header file:

```
#ifndef __CALC_H__
#define __CALC_H__
#include <iostream>

struct Calc {
  Calc();
  Calc(const Calc &other);

  bool error;
  int display;
  char oper;
  int result;
  int memory;

  void digit(int digit);
  void op(char oper);
  void equals();

  void memPlus();
  void memClear();
  void memRecall();

  bool isError() const;

  void allClear();
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Calc &c);

#endif
```

and my source file

```
#include "calc.h"

void doOperation(Calc& calc){
    switch(calc.oper){//ide tells me oper cant be resolved
    case '+':
        break;
    case '-':
        break;
    case '*':
        break;
    case '/':
        break;
    }
}

void Calc(){

}

void Calc(const Calc& other){//ide tells me Calc does not name a type

}
```

So the problems are
1.oper cannot be recognized as a data member of Calc
2.when I use Calc as parameter, eclipse cant find the type Calc
Where did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: While this might get more complicated, I am not sure that you actually need constructors for this example.  You might be interested in this tutorial http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/ which covers the basics of structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things, first constructors do not have a return type so

```
void Calc() {}
```

is not the way to go - lose the `void` return type. Second you need to use the scope resolution operator on your `Calc` member functions - again lose the `void`

```
 Calc::Calc(const Calc& other){
 }
```